# jhipster social login from mobile

Tags: mobile, jhipster

I use Jhipster backend with JWT auth method.
I would like to exctend my app with mobile clients with social login.

Is it possible to create social login from mobile
or should I use oauth method instead of JWT method?

Comment: I also need to find its solution. Please guide if you have any.